# Django- Retrieving and normalising data from mongodb

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In django project, I have connected with mongodb without creating models. I just writing data directly into collection using python code. All the collections are working independently. For example,
I have employee and employment collection(one employee has multiple employment). There is no foreignkey relationship between employee and employment.

```
# employee response
{{"emp_id": "S101", "emp_name": "Kim", "dob": "1995-12-30"}
{"emp_id": "S102", "emp_name": "Sasi", "dob": "2000-12-01"}
{"emp_id": "S103", "emp_name": "Shakthi", "dob": "2001-01-01"}}

# employment response
{{"emp_id": "S101", "employment_type": "contract", "status": "terminated", "date": "2017-04-05"},
{"emp_id": "S101", "employment_type": "contract", "status": "pending", "date": "2018-07-09"},
{"emp_id": "S102", "employment_type": "Permanent", "status": "active","date": "2017-04-05"},
{"emp_id": "S103", "employment_type": "Permanent", "status": "active", "date": "2017-04-05"}}
```

when I retrieve employee details I would like to get response like below,

```
{
{{"emp_id": "S101", "emp_name": "Kim", "dob": "1995-12-30", 
"employment_status": {{"emp_id": "S101", "employment_type": "contract", "status": "terminated", "date": "2017-04-05"},
    {"emp_id": "S101", "employment_type": "contract", "status": "pending", "date": "2018-07-09"}}
{{"emp_id": "S102", "emp_name": "Sasi", "dob": "2000-12-01", 
"employment_status":{"emp_id": "S102", "employment_type": "Permanent", "status": "active","date": "2017-04-05"}}}
}
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
   client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
        db = client["hrmdb"]
        results = db.employee.aggregate([
            {
                '$lookup': {
                    'from': "employment",
                    'localField': 'emp_id',
                    'foreignField': 'emp_id',
                    'as': 'employments'
                }
            }
        ])
        document_list = []
        for rec_value in results:
            y = json.loads(json_util.dumps(rec_value))
            document_list.append(y)
```

Above code was solved my issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).